# Align rotated labels of Altair boxplot

Tags: python, boxplot, altair

I'm plotting a boxplot graph using Altair to divide the data into groups (similar to what was done here: [Altair boxplot with nested grouping by two categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876936/altair-boxplot-with-nested-grouping-by-two-categorical-variables)) . The code I have is below:

```
import seaborn as sns
import altair as alt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

tips = tips.replace('Sun', 'Sunday morning')

chart = alt.Chart(tips).mark_boxplot(ticks=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("smoker:O", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, ticks=False), scale=alt.Scale(padding=1)), 
    y=alt.Y("total_bill:Q"), 
    color="smoker:N",
    column=alt.Column('day:N', sort=['Thur','Fri','Sat','Sunday morning'],header=alt.Header(labelPadding=-530,labelAngle=-90))
).properties(
    width=80,
    height = 350
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
```

However, I can not manage to properly position the column labels after rotating them 90 degrees. In the image below, you can see the graph I'm getting in 'a', and the graph I would like to get in 'b'.

[image]

I looked for configurations on https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html, but could not find a solution. Does anyone have an idea? (I'm using Altair 4.2.2 - the latest version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried various parameters, referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134669/rotated-column-headers-in-altair-have-uneven-offset). I got the intended result by setting the label orient to bottom and modifying the padding. I don't have as much experience with Altair as you describe.

```
import seaborn as sns
import altair as alt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

tips = tips.replace('Sun', 'Sunday morning')

chart = alt.Chart(tips).mark_boxplot(ticks=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("smoker:O", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labels=False, ticks=False), scale=alt.Scale(padding=1)), 
    y=alt.Y("total_bill:Q"), 
    color="smoker:N",
    column=alt.Column('day:N',
                      sort=['Thur','Fri','Sat','Sunday morning'],
                      header=alt.Header(
                          labelPadding=360,
                          labelAngle=-90,
                          orient='bottom',
                          labelOrient='bottom',
                          labelAlign='right'
                          
                      ))
).properties(
    width=80,
    height = 350
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
)
chart
```

[image]